# Can I override an element's inline style in my stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to force all text on one of my systems to be displayed with one font type.  However, folks frequently paste in text that has inline styles with all sorts of different formatting.

Could I override an element's inline style in my stylesheet?  '!important' isn't enough for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline styles rule supreme.

You can do this, but you'll need to do it using JavaScript. The code would have to basically remove all of the inline style statements from the pasted code. This is a good idea anyway, you never know what people will paste-in.

Using jQuery:

```
$('.wrapper *').removeAttr('style');
```

...where your content is within a div with a class of "wrapper"

Comment: I think if you're just looking to override the font-face, this solution is overkill.  Might as well re-code all the CSS at this point

Answer (score 4):

You can override inline styles using CSS code that assigns font family to all relevant elements using the `!important` specifier, e.g.

```
* { font-family: Calibri !important; }
```

It is not sufficient to set the font e.g. just on the `body` element, since then inner elements have their fonts controlled by rules applicable to them. Inner elements inherit font from their parent only if *no* CSS rule sets the font on the inner element.

If someone is able to inject an inline style that has `!important`, then you cannot beat that in CSS. You would need to manipulate the document with JavaScript, removing or changing the `style` attribute.

Comment: The ! important helped me a lot and saved my time :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need JavaScript for this. Despite what you say, `!important` is indeed enough.

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/jezen/Z4rnv/

Explanation: CSS rules are chosen based on a level of specifity, which is calculated by the layout engine. The `!important` rule isn't an all-overbearing modifier; it simply adds extra weight to the respective rule in the specificity heirarchy.

Comment: What happens when some idiot already uses !important in the inline style?

Comment: That's a fair point. I still don't like your solution, but I take back my downvote.

Comment: You're right, `!important` should be enough... but you have to set it on  `* {}`.  Perhaps consider changing your answer be more specific - `* { font-family:"Whatevs" !important;}`

Comment: Thanks, Jezen, I think I may want to remove some of the formatting with jQuery in my case, but I do appreciate that you went so far as an example! +1

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery remove attribute function should do the trick.

```
removeAttr( 'style' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't happy with the non specific nature of the other two answers.

`* { font-family: Calibri !important; }`

Won't always work sometimes you need to be more specific such as when dealing with spans

`span { font-family: Calibri !important; }`

Is specific enough because though you are adding important to the value.

Also the type of font styling matters, if the initial font styling was just using a font such as font-family and font-size are more specific already so using

`span { font:15px arial,sans-serif; !important; }`

would not override an inline style of

`<span style="font-family: Calibri">Hello World</span>`

Comment: Very good thoughts! But, for my case, what if content editors are inserting styles into divs and lists and paragraphs and not just spans... and what if they're changing colors and sizes, and not just fonts. See it gets complicated, that's why the more *general* solutions here worked for my case. :-)